# Procedure to delete the old rows leaving behind bottom 100 rows automatically(first in first out) when data is loading from scada to sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, scada

how to do first in first out in SQL Server 2008

```
USE [TEST2]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_chartData8]    Script Date: 05/24/2010 14:30:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_chartData8]
As
begin
declare @rowcount as integer
declare @deletecount as integer
declare @Totalrows as integer
set @Totalrows=10
select @rowcount=count (*) from tblBarcode;
IF (@rowcount > @Totalrows)
begin
select @deletecount=@rowcount-@Totalrows
print @Totalrows
print @rowcount
print @deletecount
delete top (@deletecount) from tblBarcode
End
End
--select * from tblBarcode
--EXEC usp_chartData8
```

when i run this then only it shows 10 rows
 i want to update automatically from SCADA to SQL

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your head around the logic.... try using traditional methods - work on a paper and then implement.

Another suggestion - If you are deleting too many rows than use a bigger batch size else transaction logs will get filled up.

```
USE [TEST2];
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_chartData8]
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @rowcount AS INTEGER;
         DECLARE @deletecount AS INTEGER;
         DECLARE @Totalrows AS INTEGER;
         SET @Totalrows = 10;
         SELECT @Totalrows = COUNT(*) -- Changed from @rowcount
         FROM tblBarcode;
         IF(@Totalrows > @rowcount ) -- Changed
             BEGIN
                 SELECT @deletecount = @Totalrows - @rowcount; -- Changed
                 PRINT @Totalrows;
                 PRINT @rowcount;
                 PRINT @deletecount;
                 DELETE TOP (@deletecount)
                 FROM tblBarcode;
             END;
     END;
```

Comment: i used " order by Date dsc " script in my stored procedure but getting error

Comment: Why do you care about the order ?... just delete